# Generating thumbnail bar with AVAssetImageGenerator

Tags: ios8, uikit

I'm using the following code to generate a bar of thumbnails:

```
NSArray *times = [self timesForDuration:_videoAsset.duration andCount:self.numberOfThumbnails];

__block int i = 0;

[_imageGenerator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:times completionHandler:^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef image, CMTime actualTime, AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error) {
    if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded) {
        UIImageView *imageView = [self imageViewForImage:image atPosition:i];

        CGImageRelease(image);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [_videoBarView addSubview:imageView];
        });
    }
    ++i;
}];
```

It sort of works, but the problem is that the view as a whole updates very slowly and you can see gaps in the bar ... after some time the bar shows all requested thumbnails as expected.

From the debugger I can tell that the thumbnail generation is actually quite fast, so what's going on here?

I've seen a workaround that will just generate each image synchronously using `copyCGImageAtTime` but that may make the UI unresponsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems seems to be caused by the creation of the `UIImageView` objects outside of the `dispatch_async` block; putting that code inside the block fixes the issues:

```
if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded) {
    __block int position = i;
    CGImageRetain(image);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIImageView *imageView = [self imageViewForImage:image atPosition:position];

        [_videoBarView addSubview:imageView];

        CGImageRelease(image);
    });
}
++i;
```